Reexpress $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ as a sum with $n!$ in the denominator
Let
\begin{equation}
    S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}.
\end{equation}
($\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ is known to diverge. )
I would like to know other ways to express this sum. A somewhat trivial observation was to realize that the denominator is nothing else than $n!$. However, I have not been able to find a closed expression for the numerator
\begin{equation}
    S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{?}{n!}
\end{equation}
As a few examples:
\begin{equation}
    S_3=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2*3+1*3+1*2}{1*2*3}=\frac{6+3+2}{3!}
\end{equation}
$$$$
\begin{equation}
    S_4=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{2*3*4+1*3*4+1*2*4+1*2*3}{1*2*3*4}=\frac{24+12+8+6}{4!}
\end{equation}
I do not seem to find a common pattern in the numerator. Is it even possible to do?

This is poorly written.  $n$ is just the dummy summation variable.  I think you meant to write something like $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac 1n=\frac ?{N!}$.

You are looking for the Stirling Numbers of the First Kind (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)

Also, one can note that $4!=24$ is not the least common multiple of $1,2,3,4:\ 12$ is. Although this is not necessarily related to the question.

Are you going along the lines of division and subtraction free formulas? This is useful when you want to make things manifestly positive and natural numbers. This can be in the context of avoiding floating point division.

One can provide a recurrence formula in addition to the suggested answers in the comments and in the adjacent answer: Taking $S(n) = n \cdot S(n-1) + (n-1)!$ with $S(2)=1$ we obtain
$$\frac{ S(n)}{n!} =\mathcal{H}_n - 1$$
where $\mathcal{H}_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$.
